# Why could GCC find the libraries for GMP, and MPFR, but not for the MPC?

Tags: gcc, fortran, header-files, include-path, mpc

- I am trying a build gcc on my Mac it is an intel Mac. I do have these libraries, the libraries are here, so it is usr/local/lib for the libraries and the headers are here usr/local/include. I also successfully compiled and install gmp and mpfr accept the mpc for some reason it is not locating.

---

gcc error:

configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 3.1.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+.
Try the --with-gmp, --with-mpfr and/or --with-mpc options to specify
their locations.  Source code for these libraries can be found at
their respective hosting sites as well as at
https://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/.  See also
http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html for additional info.  If
you obtained GMP, MPFR and/or MPC from a vendor distribution package,
make sure that you have installed both the libraries and the header
files.  They may be located in separate packages.

Mpc error:

configure: error: gmp.h cannot be found or is unusable.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask] and [mcve]. Did you run the prerequisities `./contrib/download_prerequisites` script shipped with the GCC source code? Check https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC The hard way is *not* recommended. If you do want to do it the hard way, you have to tell us how your include paths are set up.

Comment: Notably, please check how environment variables like `C_INCLUDE_PATH`, `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPATH` are set and try to add `/usr/local/include` into them.

Comment: Just in case: unless you really need to have a custom GCC installation built by yourself, it's way easier to get GCC through the [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) package manager (which also carries tons of useful unix tools).

Comment: @Vladimir F Героям слава
I have tried what you wrote about the path but I have another error after that. **'/usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/new:40:10: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
   40 | #include <bits/c++config.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [charset.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-build-libcpp] Error 2
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2'**

Comment: No idea about this error, you can ask separately, but I repeat, the hard way is **not** recommended. You should use the provided `./contrib/download_prerequisites` instead.